# getting the path name files in a directory in q

Tags: kdb

I am using q to get all the files listed in that directory:

`` key `:Dname ``

and then try to filter out the the ones that start with numbers as:

`` key `:Dname like "[0-9]" ``

but the like part does not quite work. I tried `get` as well since I like the path to include the directory that the file is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that q evaluate expressions from right to left. Your code here will first evaluate

```
`:Dname like "[0-9]"
```

and apply `key` to the result.

You want something closer to

```
key[`:Dname] like "[0-9]"
```

But to get what you want you'll have to add a wildcard to the pattern string that you're supplying and apply `not` to the result

```
not key[`:Dname] like "[0-9]*"
```

This will give you a boolean vector, to return the list of files you want use where and index:

```
key[`:Dname] where not key[`:Dname] like "[0-9]*"
```

Comment: This works well. If I wanted to add in the original directory path do I just concatenate it to the returns or is there an option in key that returns it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a filename defined like

```
filename:`2019.01.20file.txt
```

You can compare this to a pattern using `like`, similar to what you have done:

```
filename like "[0-9]*"
```

- `"*"` is the wildcard symbol which means that anything can come after the [0-9]
- `like` compares a string or symbol to a pattern

So this line return a 1b if the filename starts with a digit between 0 and 9.

Another method would be to compare the start of the filename to .Q.n which is a string of 0-9.
This can be achieved like so:

```
first[string filename] in .Q.n
```

- `string` converts the symbol to a string for `in` to compare it to the string .Q.n

For your situation, I would recommend the first method.

```
q)key `:q
`README.txt`q.k`q.q`s.k`sp.q`w32
q)key[`:q] like "q*"
011000b
q)x where (x:key[`:q]) like "q*"
`q.k`q.q
q)x where not (x:key[`:q]) like "q*"
`README.txt`s.k`sp.q`w32
```

This method returns the Boolean list which indicates whether each file starts with "q":

- Uses `not` to reverse the 1s and 0s of this list
- Uses `where` to return the indexes at which the Boolean list is equal to 1
- Indexes into `` key[`:q] `` with this list

I hope this helps