# Iterating over a directory within q and assigning the file path / names to a variable

Tags: kdb

I am trying iterate over a directory and get the file path + file name for each of those files.

For eg., I use `\cd` to enter the `/tmp` directory that I want to iterate over which say has two files...

```
hello_world_1.q
hello_world_2.q
```

and then try the following...

```
directoryPath: "/tmp"
fileList: directoryPath ,/: key ` sv get directoryPath
```

where fileList would be

```
"/tmp/hello_world_1.q"
"/tmp/hello_world_2.q"
```

But instead I get a type error at `sv`. Anyone know what might be the issue?

Note: it looks like the reason I get a type error is because `get directoryPath` doesn't seem to do anything

I've checked this...

[getting the path name files in a directory in q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464544/getting-the-path-name-files-in-a-directory-in-q?rq=2)

And...

```
key `:directoryPath
```

but that seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File paths should be a `hsym` (`symbol` starting with `:`)

`.Q.dd` makes creating paths much easier.

```
q)directoryPath: hsym `$"/path/to/your/directory"
q)directoryPath
`:/path/to/your/directory
q)fileList: .Q.dd[directoryPath] each key directoryPath
q)fileList
`:/path/to/your/directory/hello_world_1.q`:/path/to/your/directory/hello_world_2.q
```

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/hsym/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#dd-join-symbols

If you wanted to filter a folder to only return `.q` files:

```
fileList: .Q.dd[directoryPath] each {x where x like "*.q"}key directoryPath
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I guess that `hysm` was the important piece. If I want to also just get the file names like `hello_world_1` into a separate list - how would that work? I am trying to mess around with `{x where x like "*.*"} key directoryPath`

Comment: Hi. Coming back to this - is there a way to do this so nested folders are checked as well? The above only adds the nested folder but not its contents

Comment: I ended up doing something like fileList: system "find /path/to/files/ -type f"